# How do you call a method from static main()?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application with a `Main` method and a function.

How can I make a function call from the `Main` method?

I know the code below won't work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
   string btchid = GetCommandLine();// GetCommandline is a mthod which returns a string
}
```

Comment: Is GetCommandLine() a static method?

Comment: The best way to remember the basics when you forget them, is to study them again. At least that's what I do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's also

```
var p = new Program();
string btchid = p.GetCommandLine();
```

Comment: It is wonder coming a bunch of years that while immediately calling from static main() method is possible, why not in C#? Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 13):

Make the `GetCommandLine` `static`!

```
namespace Lab
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static string GetCommandLine()
        {
            return "Hellow World!";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(GetCommandLine());
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem :-). Good luck with mastering the basics again!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the function as a static and call it . Thats all.

Answer (score 2):

```
static class Program
{        
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string btchid = Program.GetCommandLine();
    }

    private static string GetCommandLine()
    {
        string s = "";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A linear search approach to your problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LinearSearch
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int var1 = 50;
        int[] arr;
        arr = new int[10]{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
        int retval = linearsearch(arr,var1);
         if (retval >= 1)
         {
           Console.WriteLine(retval);
           Console.Read();
         }
         else
         { Console.WriteLine("Not found"); Console.Read(); }
    }

    static int linearsearch(int[] arr, int var1)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        int posfound = 0;
        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            pos = pos + 1;
            if (item == var1)
            {
                posfound = pos;
                if (posfound >= 1)
                    break;
            }     
        }  
        return posfound;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetCommandLine` must be a static function

Answer (score 0):

`string btchid = classnamehere.GetCommandLine();`
Assuming that `GetCommandLine` is static

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string btchid = GetCommandLine();// GetCommandline is a mthod which returns a string 
}

static string GetCommandLine(){
    return "Some command line";
}
```