# How to pass values inputted by user in main method to another method in C#?

Tags: c#

How to pass inputted values of user in main method to my Add() method parameter? And also how to output the result to my Add() method?

```
     int Add(int a,int b)
     {
        return a + b;
     }
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        Console.WriteLine("Input any whole number: ");
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Input any whole number again: ");
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     }
```

Comment: int num3 = Add(num1,num2);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you call a method from static main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728494/how-do-you-call-a-method-from-static-main)

Answer (score 7):

You should make your `Add` method `static` here, because it should be callable from the static `Main` method.

```
public static int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Then you will need to save the result from an `Add` method call in a variable (`result` for example) and output it to the console. You could add these lines to the bottom of your `Main` method:

```
int result = Add(num1, num2);
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 4):

A more object-oriented approach would be to put it into a new class and use it:

```
public class MyCalculator
{
    public int Add(int a,int b)
    {
       return a + b;
    }
}


 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    ...
    var calculator = new MyCalculator();        
    var res = calculator.Add(num1, num2);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
 }
```

However if we think about it a bit more it is not that obvious. For example class `Math` in `.Net` is static so specifically for objects like calculator you might want to make them static as well:

```
public static class MyCalculator
{
    public static int Add(int a,int b)
    {
       return a + b;
    }
}
```

And use it like this `MyCalculator.Add(x1, x2);`

Comment: Putting it in a separate class seems like a good refactoring step to me. But making the new class static would not be my advice; regular classes can be more easily dependency-injected and unit-tested, for example...

Comment: @BartHofland It is not without a reason why in .NET framework class `Math` is static

Comment: Yes. I agree. The `Math` class contains only general mathematical methods that are used quite a lot. You don't want to create a `Math` object each time you want to do some arithmetic. So in this case you are probably right, assuming that the `MyCalculator` class will remain simple and straightforward as well. But I am generally very cautious with creating static classes.

Comment: A bit more info on the subject: [when should I make a class static](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103914/why-and-when-should-i-make-a-class-static-what-is-the-purpose-of-static-key)

Comment: I don't want to end up here in the already quite long-running discussion about static classes and singleton patterns. Here, I only want to indicate that I disagree with the author of the accepted question in your link when it comes to the general applicance of static classes. You might want to create another `Math` or `MyCalculator` class (based on a shared interface, but with a different implementation, just to get the same results in a different way). And then you want to have the choice (in runtime) to switch between one implementation or the other. That is impossible with static classes.

Comment: I have to add one more clarifying comment. Sorry. ... When following SOLID design principles and using design patterns where possible (and applicable), you probably want to be able to implement interfaces for your classes and assign concrete class instances in runtime to interface-typed variables/parameters. That's what I mean with runtime switching of implementations. Typically, you do not want to talk to concrete class instances at all; you want to talk to a class instance's interface. That enables loose coupling and inversion of control. But all that does not work with static classes.

Comment: In general, you need to have a pretty compelling reason to use static classes (aka singletons) in C# over other solutions, since they can cause lots of hidden bugs, especially with concurrent programming.